# In Python How to get List of Lists from String that looks like List of Lists

Tags: python

I am reading the data from other system and I have it as a string. I want to change it to List object having Lists inside, so I can work with it. Is there some easy way? Would prefer without extra libraries.

```
my_string = '[["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["a1", "b1", "c1", ""], ["a2", "b2", "", "d2"]]'
print(type(my_string)) # <class 'str'>
```

Thank you

Comment: you got a string and want lists?

Comment: yep, want List of Lists.

Comment: if the answer helped dont forget to mark the accepted answe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` (be careful with this function though)

```py
print(eval(my_string))
```

Comment: Eval its a dangerous operation that can cause vulnerability to the whole program...

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you need to use the json module for this specific case:

```
import json

#... more code
list_of_lists = json.loads(my_string)
print(list_of_lists[0][0])
>>>a
```

Answer (score 1):

** Use python in-built eval() function here and get your list as required **

```
x = eval(my_string)
>>> type(x)
   <class 'list'>
>>> x[0]
   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> x[1]
   ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', '']
>>> x[2]
   ['a2', 'b2', '', 'd2']
```